# Ruby or Rails sort on two/multiple date fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Seems simple enough- I'd like to combine two model queries and sort them all by date DESC, but the date fields are named differently.

```
@news_and_posts = [News.all(:limit => 3, :order => "date_of_news DESC") + Post.all(:limit => 3, :order => "date_of_post DESC")
```

I've tried

```
@news_and_posts = [News.all(:limit => 3, :order => "date_of_news DESC") + Post.all(:limit => 3, :order => "date_of_post DESC").sort_by {|n, p| [n.date_of_news, p.date_of_post]}
```

Thanks!

Comment: use an alias (a method called 'get_date' for example) implemented on each model. Then do a `.sort{|i,j| i.get_date <=> j.get_date }`

Comment: @MrYoshiji: that's the easiest yes. But I'd write `.sort_by(&:get_date)`.

Comment: @tokland What are the differences between sort & sort_by in this case ?

Comment: well, for starters is more concise and more declarative, but it's also more efficient, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use an alias returning the date (a method called 'date' for example) implemented in each model you want to compare.

Then sort your list by this `date` :

(Thanks to @tokland for a better implementation)

```
my_collection.sort_by(&:date)
```

Comment: +1, although the `get` in `get_date` feels a bit unidiomatic in Ruby

Comment: Agreed. I replaced the method name get_date to date.