# PostgreSQL in Rails: sorting object by two date attributes in descending order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sorting, activerecord

I have an index of active job positions. Currently, they're sorted by the most recent i.e. `created_at`. However, recently i've added in a renewal feature that updates a `renewal_date` attribute without updating the `created_at`.

What I want to achieve is to sort the list in descending order using both `renewal_date` and `created_at`.

```
jobs = Job.where(active: true).reorder("renewal_date DESC NULLS LAST", "created_at DESC")
```

With this code, the renewed job will always be at the top regardless of how many new jobs are created. How do I sort it so it checks for the date for both attributes and sorts it according to most recent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will order first by renewal_date with nulls at the end, and then will look at the created_at if two records have the same renewal_date.

I assume that what you want to do is something like "max(renewal_date, created_at)", which will take the "last modification date", or another custom way to compare the two fields.
If then, you can find your answer here : [merge and order two columns in the same model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35206355/merge-and-order-two-columns-in-the-same-model)

```
Job.where(active: true).reorder('GREATEST(renewal_date, created_at) DESC')
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. This helped me alot!

Answer (score 2):

Let try a standard SQL, so it can work with all types of database:

```
Job.where(active: true).order('CASE WHEN renewal_date IS NULL THEN created_at ELSE renewal_date END DESC')
```