# Rails: sort association includes without issuing new query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

Person
`has_many: :blogs`
`has_many: :articles`

Blog
`has_one: :person`

Problem:

`person.<blogs and articles>.<order by last_updated>.last`

I know that I can have a scope so that all returned blogs are automagically ordered by last time, but is there a way to return all blogs and articles sorted by time? Essentially, I'm looking for the last updated child of a parent object.

Comment: `person.blogs.order('blogs.last_updated desc').last` should work no?

Comment: I apologize, I phrased the question incorrectly. I corrected it, but your comment would have been a valid answer to the question, certainly.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14201179/7265539) might help

Answer (score 0):

You can collate the results of both queries and call sort on the resulting array.

`(person.blogs + person.articles).sort_by(&:last_updated).last`